# How to set up recurring payments for selling subscription products in Shopify

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopify, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up a Shopify store that sells subscription products so I need recurring payments. I know there are a couple options like PayPal or Chargify but are there any better options out there? I'm not sure how easy the PayPal implementation would be (I'd love feedback about that) and Chargify is really expensive. I also tried Shopify's Stripe integration but Shopify doesn't send Stripe the full payment info so I couldn't set up a recurring payment inside of Stripe. I'm also open to other products outside of Shopify if anyone has suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't work for Chargify or Shopify BUT...

I guess you need to define really expensive? The cheap plan for Chargify subscriptions is ~$120 a month... which amounts to an average Joe's coffee budget.

I setup Stripe for a client so that when they make a payment on a "page" with the Stripe payment form, a recurring payment is initiated and the customer account info is transferred to Stripe too. Until Shopify introduces recurring payments, this is a decent stopgap measure.